# WCF REST POST of JSON: Parameter is empty

Tags: wcf, json, fiddler

Using Fiddler I post a JSON message to my WCF service. The service uses System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebServiceHostFactory

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke
(UriTemplate = "/authenticate",
       Method = "POST",
       ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
       BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest
       )]
String Authorise(String usernamePasswordJson);
```

When the POST is made, I am able to break into the code, but the parameter **usernamePasswordJson** is **null**. Why is this?

Note: Strangly when I set the **BodyStyle** to **Bare**, the post doesn't even get to the code for me to debug.

Here's the Fiddler Screen:
[image]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You declared your parameter as type String, so it is expecting a JSON string - and you're passing a JSON object to it.

To receive that request, you need to have a contract similar to the one below:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyInterface
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/authenticate",
           Method = "POST",
           ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
           BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
    String Authorise(UserNamePassword usernamePassword);
}

[DataContract]
public class UserNamePassword
{
    [DataMember]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Fantastic. That worked like a dream. After a day of frustration, I finally have a solution.

Comment: Fantastic, i was struggling with null data passed into service and your suggestion resolved the issue.  Thanks for sharing.

Comment: I think the magic line `BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare` was what had been stumping me for past *don't want to count* hours! Thanks for posting this snippet!