# POST Request empty in REST service

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, http

I've experimented with my own REST service as a WCF service, but I am having problems when I try to POST to the service from a client.

Here is the Service code:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IBookService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "AddBook/")]
    string AddBook(HttpRequestMessage request);
}


public class BookService : IBookService
{
    static IBookRepository repository = new BookRepository();

    public string AddBook(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        try
        {
            // request is always empty.
            var content = request.Content;
            Book tempBook = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Book>(content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
            repository.AddNewBook(tempBook);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //
        }
        return "AddBookTest";
    }
}
```

Here is the client code:

```
    var client = new HttpClient();
    var url = new Uri("http://localhost:53258/");
    client.BaseAddress = url;
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    var tempBook = new Book() { BookId = 10, Title = "Title", ISBN = "123143234"};
    var serializedBook = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tempBook);
    HttpContent content = new StringContent(serializedBook, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

    var postResponse = _client.PostAsync("AddBook/", content).Result;

    if (!postResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        // Always returns 400 Bad request.
```

The POST calls the AddBook method, but the HttpRequestMessage object is always empty:

[image]

I've researched for hours now, yet I can't come up with another relatively simple solution.
Any kind souls that can help me figure out what I am missing?

EDIT: Web.Config code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="MyRestService.BookService" behaviorConfiguration="bookServiceBehavior">
        <endpoint address=""
                  binding="webHttpBinding"
                  contract="MyRestService.IBookService"
                  behaviorConfiguration="RESTEndpointBehavior" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="RESTEndpointBehavior">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="bookServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="false"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: did you implemented a binding changes in web.config in your service ?

Comment: ok you have already did the required binding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer did the trick. 
I had already tried something similar, but I must've missed something along the way.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6836030/4063668

I ended up with this declaration in my interface:

```
[OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "AddBook/", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
        string AddBook(Book request);
```